# Why this button in Navigation bar is not working ? Is there any problem in code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, responsive-navigation

I do this offline and download all the files which need for the run bootstrap properly and  add connect all the links

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWMGM.jpg
```

Comment: Can you show me the console injection on developer mode (F12) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call other files inside bootstrapp , try adding all css links at head
and js links at the bottom
the button using some css and js files.
I hope it s working.